# Assigning attributes with a has_many through relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm just wondering if someone could explain to me how to create a relationship (programmatic example would be helpful, so I can test in rails console) between two objects where the relationship is defined as a has_many :through that has additional attributes.  The objects are defined as below:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :collections, :through => :collection_items
end
```

---

```
class Collection < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items, :through => :collection_items
end
```

---

```
class CollectionItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :collection
  belongs_to :item

  attr_accessible :collection_id, :item_id, :quantity
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
CollectionItem.create(item_id: Item.first, collection_id: Collection.first, quantity: 999)
```

Just replace the '`Item.first`' and '`Collection.first`' with whatever logic you have to get the right item and collection.

Comment: Ok, so in this case we create the relationship object instead of adding one of the members to the other's collection (collection may have been a bad name to use in my example classes, referring to the object collections here ie. items, collections)?

Comment: Well, I think you could also write something like: `Item.collectionItems.create(quantity: 999, collection_id: Collection.first)`.